# Memory leak using ngOnChanges hook

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, ngonchanges

I am facing an issue with a memory leak when using the `ngOnChanges` hook to access the changes to an input property in my child component.
I am sending a large amount of data (an array with 27000 items) from my parent component and the data within the array is changing at a frequency of at least 30hz.
I think that the garbage collector is not removing the references of the `previousValue` in the `changes: SimpleChanges` object at the same frequency as mentioned above. Is there a manual way I can dispose of the data from the object or is there a more efficient way of accessing the changes on the input property other than the hook? Please correct me if that is not the root cause of the memory leak? I can share my code if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by disposing of the old array references immeaditaley after I had processed the old data

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of knowing from the details of your question if `ngOnChanges` is causing a memory leak - if it's a recent version of Angular I would imagine it's pretty unlikely

As a way of ruling it out, you could use property accessors with `@Input` instead of `ngOnChanges`

```js
private _data: any[];

@Input() set data(value: any[]) {
  this._data = value;
  this.runUpdates();
}
get data(): any[] {
  // other logic
  return this._data;
}
```

When using the above approach, make sure to pass in a new array via the input binding i.e. the setter won't be triggered via array mutations